# Assigning snap value to variable in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am begginer to Javascript and Firebase and would like to know how I can do to return the snap value to out of FIRE and assign it to the variable Look this:

```
var fire = firebase.database().ref("s/login");
var login = null;
fire.on('value', snap => login = snap.val());
alert(login);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback `snap => ...` will be executed **after** `alert(login)`, so your alert will show `null`.

You should have:

```
var fire = firebase.database().ref("s/login");
var login = null;
fire.on('value', snap => {
    login = snap.val();
    alert(login);
});
```

You may want to read about [reading and writing values with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write).

[Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/) is a useful page to learn about control flow in JavaScript.

Comment: I would like to return snap.val to out of fire. How can i do it? @MattMS

Comment: The code will assign `snap.val()` to `login` inside the `fire.on()` callback scope. Because these Firebase functions are asynchronous (like most JavaScript), you cannot access it in a synchronous way, as you originally posted.

Comment: To be clear, your `login` value will be available elsewhere after `fire.on` has run (since you declared `var login` outside of it), but you only know when it has been set inside that callback function.

Comment: Got it. But could you please explain to me why the flow of Javascript code behaves differently?

Comment: If I put an alert ("hi") within the scope of fire.on and an alert ("bye") outside and below the scope of fire.on, the last alert will be displayed first. Why is the flow not linear? Is there a way to make this flow linear?

Comment: I'm having difficulty because it seems like the execution time of the firebase query functions, for example, is slower which is longer execution time of the javascript functions. How can I make synchronous communication? @MattMS

Comment: No, the flow only goes via the callbacks, so there is no way to make the calls happen synchronously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133312/discussion-between-isaac-meneses-and-mattms).